# Arbitrarily sort favorite tags

Tags: feature-request

For example, I've just added `[javafx-8]` to my list of favorite tags, which already contained `[javafx]` as well as `[javafx-3d]`. I'd like to sort my favorite tags so that these three are side by side. Currently, new tags are simply added to the end, hence, there's possibly a big gap between tags that somewhat belong together from an user perspective.

Comment: Someone can doubtless write a userscript to save and remove favorite tags, then re-add them at the end, which effectively provides re-ordering.

Comment: Do you know you can `*` wildcard in favourite (and ignored) tags?

Comment: @AakashM no, I didn't. Thanks for the hint, but it's orthogonal to sorting I think.